# Writing a function that picks values from an object and return the correct types

Tags: typescript

I have a function that pulls a value based on the string you give it. When I execute the function how do I make the output of the function typed to the value it has pulled out.

```
const config = {
  one: 'one-string',
  two: 'two-string',
  three: true,
  four: {
    five: 'five-string',
    six: false
  },
  seven: [
    'eight', 'nine', 'ten'
  ]
}

type Config = {
  one: string;
  two: string;
  three: boolean;
  four: {
    five: string;
    six: boolean;
  }
  seven: string[]
}

type GetConfig = (key: keyof Config) => Config[keyof Config];

export const getConfig: GetConfig = key => {
  return config[key];
};

getConfig('seven').map(...);
```

Currently I get the following error:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | boolean | string[] | {
> five: string; six: boolean; }'.   Property 'map' does not exist on
> type 'string'.

because `getConfig` isn't being typed as an array as it is indicated above rather it's just being typed as any one of the possible types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `GetConfig` type generic, `getConfig` will be typed correctly:

```
type GetConfig = <K extends keyof Config>(key: K) => Config[K];
```

Alternatively, you can specify the generic type directly on the constant, so you don't have to explicitly specify a return type:

```
const getConfigAlt = <K extends keyof Config>(key: K) => config[key];
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzGBeGBvAsAKBhnAFMAuGAchIFpoAnJMFCgGn0KgHcRyKuRaUBk1bsYUABZ1iZcXQCuxNgRgIQ8uuVwrCyAG6yK%204oOHNlhQhCQAPcggCGAGwjExAXwsxXBsOQDaYoQUxKgSUKyUYIzEkXzEYBRiALr47vj4UACeAA7EMADC4MhomNqEJOT0jCgA3GL8VUI19SqS0rIARiAgTsQOYK266prYQapIBk1mQ5bWdjDdvf2DHmI%20CdM1-ql46XiZufkA4sRQRYioGDAAPADSMMQ2UAkAJhAwANbEWSAIhcVUAA%20AAU3yy5DuAEoMECAZcUP47slWvh4NAYCgzhcSuRTudAaUvj9YWMVNIoBowHBCf5wSi0qi8FiCQiQRQNokoQA6AC2DhyII%206DhEG5UBAAFUcnk6AUHK4QVCoUz0bAWTjUABBJywTD3R7PN4fcF-eElUHgyEwkU0hF0n4Mg7M7GEnVQdmcig8-mC4Wi8VSmXEOUK4hKlX4IA)

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I was trying to get to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this can try it one typescript playground

```
    const config = {
    one: 'one-string',
    two: 'two-string',
    three: true,
    four: {
        five: 'five-string',
        six: false
    },
    seven: ['eight', 'nine', 'ten']
}

type Config = {
    one: string;
    two: string;
    three: boolean;
    four: {
        five: string;
        six: boolean;
    }
    seven: string[];
}

type GetConfig = (key: keyof Config) => Config[keyof Config];

const getConfig: GetConfig = key => {
  return config[key];
};

const val = getConfig('seven').valueOf() as [];
val.map(m => {
    console.log(m);
});
```